# LZ4 crashes when it compresses a file on mips (little endian) and decompresses it on x86 (big endian)

Tags: compression, embedded-linux, lz4

I have a problem using LZ4 compression algorithm on devices with different architecture.

Here is the scenario:

- I have  two devices one mips32 with openwrt OS and another is x86 (32bit)
  ubuntu
- mips is little endian and x86 is big endian
- I used lz4 git code form https://github.com/lz4/lz4 and
  compiled for each device
- When I compress a file on mips device or x86
  and decompress it in the same device all is OK, but when I compress
  a file on the mips and decompress it in the x86 or vice versa it could not
  decompress it and returns a zero size file.

It seems that lz4 should work in different architectures but I could not find what is going on here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Bests,

Majid.

Comment: x86 is little endian.  MIPS is bi-endian (it can be either little or big endian).  I've used LZ4 on both little-endian and big-endian (power8be); I can confirm that it works.  Without a way to reproduce this (such as a qemu image) you're probably going to need to provide a *lot* more information, or debug it yourself.

Comment: lz4 is compatible and interoperable with both little and big endian systems. You might have found a corner case. Try to force LZ4 endian mode, by modifying directly the source code : https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/dev/lib/lz4.c#L162. This should help confirm if this is the problem.
Btw, do you compress your data with the API, or with the CLI ?